# Bash - getting a unknown amount of arguments from inside a script

Tags: linux, bash, arguments, minecraft

I am trying to this for a Minecraft server I have, basically it looks in the chat for a certain word and then responds to it.

This is the code I have:

```
echo [INFO] Started
while true; do
    tail -n 1 logs/latest.log > lookin.txt
    if grep -q ".df" lookin.txt
    then
        echo [$(date +'%r')][CMD] Toggledownfall
        echo ' ' > lookin.txt
        screen -S mc -X eval 'stuff "toggledownfall\015"'
        sleep 0.1
    fi

    if grep -q '.day' lookin.txt
    then
        echo [$(date +'%r')][CMD] Time set day
        echo ' ' > lookin.txt
        screen -S mc -X eval 'stuff "time set day\015"'
        sleep 0.1
    fi

    if grep -q '.night' lookin.txt
    then
        echo [$(date +'%r')][CMD] Time set night
        echo ' ' > lookin.txt
        screen -S mc -X eval 'stuff "time set night\015"'
        sleep 0.1
    fi


    if grep -q '.gm 1' lookin.txt
    then
        echo [$(date +'%r')][CMD] Gamemode 1 creeper_prey
        echo ' ' > lookin.txt
        screen -S mc -X eval 'stuff "gamemode 1 creeper_prey\015"'
        sleep 0.1
    fi
    if grep -q '.gm 0' lookin.txt
    then
        echo [$(date +'%r')][CMD] Gamemode 1 creeper_prey
        echo ' ' > lookin.txt
        screen -S mc -X eval 'stuff "gamemode 1 creeper_prey\015"'
        sleep 0.1
    fi
    if grep -q '.gm' lookin.txt
    then
        echo [$(date +'%r')][CMD][ATTEMPT] Gamemode
        echo ' ' > lookin.txt
        screen -S mc -X eval 'stuff "say Only ops are allow to use gamemode\015"'
        sleep 0.1
    fi
###############################################
    if grep -q '.test' lookin.txt
    then
        echo $1
        echo ' ' > lookin.txt
        screen -S mc -X eval 'stuff "say argumentsGoHere\015"'
        sleep 0.1
    fi
################################################
done
```

What I want to do is to get the arguments that is given with '.test' and print them where 'ArgumentsGoHere' is. The code with .test is the bit in #'s

Comment: What do you mean by __arguments__? Are they part of the line that contains `.test` or are they the arguments to the script itself?

Comment: So like, if it finds '.test random sentence here' it will say 'random sentence here'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design is not exactly the best. You should consider using `tail` with the `-f` switch (if available for your version) as so:

```
while read -r line; do
    # do stuff with line
done < <(tail -f -n0 logs/latest.log)
```

This will avoid reading the whole file entirely at each iteration and you won't need the `sleep 0.1` trick. This also avoids the use of the auxiliary file `looking.txt`.

Now, I guess you want to check whether the line *starts* with the commands. For this, you should use `case` as so:

```
case $line in
    (.df)
        echo "[$(date +'%r')][CMD] Toggledownfall"
        screen -S mc -X eval 'stuff "toggledownfall\015"' # I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here
        ;;
    (.day)
        ...
esac
```

Now, regarding your *arguments* for test: the corresponding case statement should be:

```
(.test *)
    read -r -a args <<< "$line"
    # At this point you have an array args that contains all the arguments.
    screen -S mc -X eval 'stuff "say ${args[@]:1}\015"' # This looks very dangerous to me
    ;;
```

Now, be very very careful, since you're using `eval` with unsanitized user input! A user could write `.test $(rm / -rf)` or any other evil command!!! **Don't use `eval` here!**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65169/discussion-on-answer-by-gniourf-gniourf-bash-getting-a-unknown-amount-of-argum).